# ArcGIS 10.2 Release Date

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-platform

Anyone have an idea on an ArcGIS 10.2 release date? I wans't even aware of it until stumbling upon this article: [UC Agenda Sneak Peek: Part I](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/ucinsider/2013/03/18/uc-agenda-sneak-peek-part-i/?scvn=esri&scsrc=uc2013&sctp=email&sccrtv=SneakPeek_15754&sckw=na&WT.mc_id=EmailCampaign15754)

Comment: -1 Not really a Question

Comment: this question could be the same http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54488/has-esri-made-any-definitive-announcements-about-10-1-sp2

Comment: This is a great question to ask in chat :-).

Answer (score 7):

Looks like June 2013. Please see the attached link First paragragh.

http://www.esri.com/events/devsummit

Mike

Comment: They tend to do these releases around the time of the UC.

Comment: UC Q&A now says "ArcGIS 10.2 will be available to download shortly after the User Conference." - conference dates are July 8-12 2013.